# Tiny yolo v4 dnn module opencv no detection

Tags: opencv, yolo, dotnetnuke

I'have trained yolo-tiny-v4 on colab and the detection works well on colab.
Then I've tried to load the yolo-tiny-v4 in this way on visual studio integrated with Gazebo/ROS:

[image]

No error appears, but the detection fails (no object detected, the output of the detection is a vector of Nan).
I'm using OpenCV Version: 4.2.0 and Python 2.7.17 in visual studio.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you applying the same amount of preprocessing to the images ? Like are they of the same size as the input of the model?

Comment: i have tried with python3 and it works , the problem is ROS because i have old version of ROS and it works only with python 2 ,                                                               
python3 opencv_master/samples/dnn/object_detection.py --input img1.jpg --config tiny_yolo_v4/custom-yolov4-tiny-detector.cfg --model tiny_yolo_v4/custom-yolov4-tiny-detector_final.weights --width 416 --height 416 --scale 0.00392 --rgb --thr 0                    can i solve this issue using python2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling `OpenCV >= v4.5.0` from sources.

Compiling version 4.5.0 from sources solved the issue for me in Python 3 and I checked it also works in Python 2.7.

I initially got the same issue with Yolo Tiny v4 and Python 3.7, both on Raspberry Pi 4 and Windows 7, with OpenCV installed via `pip install opencv-contrib-python` (seems not available for Python 2.7 ?).
I tried different versions iteratively, got from `pip` or recompiled from sources (latest version available via `pip` on Raspbian was 4.1.0.25):

```
opencv-contrib-python==3.4.10.37 no detections (tested on Windows)
opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25: no detections (tested on Rasbian Buster and Windows)
opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34: no detections (tested on Windows)
opencv-contrib-python==4.3.0.38: no detections (tested on Windows)
opencv 4.4.0 compiled from sources: no detections (tested on  Rasbian Buster)
opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.40: ok (tested on Windows)
opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.46: ok (testd on Windows)
opencv 4.5.0 compiled from sources: ok (tested on Rasbian Buster)
```

Versions a little after opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.40 seemed to works, so the "next" version available on Raspbian at the time was v4.5.0 from sources.

Comment: is there yolov4-tiny weight cfg files to replace python opecnv program running the older yolov3-tiny?

Comment: @Patopato Doing this fixed the nan issue. I no more see NaN values in the output. But my predictions are still 0 even though they were above 90% in google colab for the same image. Do you have any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: @kristoph One of the author has a well furnished Github for yolov4 and a model zoo with .cfg and .weight files that can be used e.g. with cv2.dnn.readFromDarkNet()
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/YOLOv4-model-zoo

Comment: @crazy_abdul Maybe check the format of the input image, e.g. RGB or gray... also the scale, on the last model I used with OpenCV it the YoloTiniV4 expected input  normalized between 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: @Patopato Thanks for the help. In the end it was the [opencv object detection python file](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/8c25a8eb7b10fb50cda323ee6bec68aa1a9ce43c/samples/dnn/object_detection.py) that worked for me. None of the tutorials I followed worked. My opencv version is still the compiled 4.5.0 from your answer and everything works fine